# Python split string based on conditional

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I want to split strings using a comma delimiter if the comma is preceded by a certain regex. Consider the case where my strings are in the format:
"(bunch of stuff that might have commas) FOO_REGEX, (other stuff that might have commas) FOO_REGEX, ..." and I want to split the string on commas, but only if they're preceded by FOO_REGEX: ["(bunch of stuff that might have commas) FOO_REGEX", "(other stuff that might have commas) FOO_REGEX", tc.].

As a concrete example, consider splitting the following string:

```
"hi, hello! $$asdf, I am foo, bar $$jkl, cool"
```

into this list of three strings:

```
["hi, hello! $$asdf", 
"I am foo, bar $$jkl", 
"cool"]
```

Is there any easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.findall` instead of `re.split`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "hi, hello! $$asdf, I am foo, bar $$jkl, cool"
>>> [j for i in re.findall(r'(.*?\$\$[^,]*),\s*|(.+)', s) for j in i if j]
['hi, hello! $$asdf', 'I am foo, bar $$jkl', 'cool']
```

**OR**

Use external [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module to support variable length lookbehind since `re` won't support variable length look-behind assertions.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "hi, hello! $$asdf, I am foo, bar $$jkl, cool"
>>> regex.split(r'(?<=\$\$[^,]*),\s*', s)
['hi, hello! $$asdf', 'I am foo, bar $$jkl', 'cool']
```

Comment: Hope this gets added soon. Because the link you gave is awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive look-behind if the FOO_REGEX is fixed-width. Here, you will get your line split after "$$asdf,"

See a [sample working program](http://goo.gl/lXHwIC):

```
import re    
str = 'hi, hello! $$asdf, I am foo, bar $$jkl, cool'
splts = re.split('(?<=\$\$asdf), *', str)
print splts
```

Output:

```
['hi, hello! $$asdf', 'I am foo, bar $$jkl, cool']
```